# Postgresql pgagent run a job from another job

Tags: postgresql, sql-job, pgagent

I have 4 jobs in pgagent that I would like to execute in a specific order from one master job. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right, they run in alphabetical order. This is the case for the [Steps](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.14/pgagent-steps.html).

Comment: you didn't get it I want to know how can I trigger a job from another job's step